# What is this sort of book in the Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, ide

Today I've came accross this kind of *book* (or maybe a chipset? lol) standing at a `if` condition on my code.

[image]

What exactly does it represent?

Comment: looks like Bookmark

Comment: I can't remove it!

Comment: Goto this line. Then right-click -> Toggle bookmark -> 9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a *Bookmark*.

You can set bookmark two-ways :

> CTRL + SHIFT + 1-9 sets up bookmark,
>
> CTRL + 1-9 Goes to bookmark

or

> Right click on the left side of editor and set up/go to / delete bookmark.
>   It's convenient to jump to another, marked parts of code.

Regards

Comment: Also Ctrl+K 0-9 sets it and Ctrl+Q 0-9 goes to it. (and bookmark numbers start at 0)